# Retorno getInstallments Pagseguro

Tags: jquery, json

O `getInstallments` do PagSeguro serve para retornar a quantidade de parcelas e o valor de cada parcela, ao informar um cartão e o valor da venda.

O retorno que obtenho é este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste retorno cada item representa uma quantidade de parcelas e seu valor, o que não estou conseguindo é usar o `foreach` de alguma forma neste retorno e preencher um `Select options`.

Gostaria de preencher o `select` com a quantidade de parcela e o valor.

Para retornar os valores estou usando:

```
PagSeguroDirectPayment.getInstallments({
    amount: <?php echo $total_compra?>,
    brand: $("#bandeira").val(),
    maxInstallmentNoInterest: 2,
    success: function(response) {
        //console.log(response);

        bandeira = $("#bandeira").val();
        $("#parcelas_div").show(200);


        var options = "";
        var retorno_bandeira = response.installments.visa;

        for (var i = 0; i < retorno_bandeira.length; i++) {
            var quantidade = retorno_bandeira[i].quantity;
            var parcela = retorno_bandeira[i].installmentAmount;
            var valorTotal = retorno_bandeira[i].totalAmount;

            options += '<option value="' + quantidade + '" data-valor="' + parcela + '">' + quantidade + 'x de ' + parcela + ' = R$ ' + valorTotal + '</option>';
        }

        $("#parcelas").html(options);


    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    complete: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

O problema que está ocorrendo é o seguinte:

Se coloco na linha `var retorno_bandeira = response.installments+"."+bandeira;` retorno de todos os dados vem `Undefined`, mas, se adiciono o nome da bandeira diretamente na linha assim `response.installments.visa;` vem tudo normal, acredito que o problema esteja na forma de concatenar o nome da bandeira ao retorno.

Comment: Coloca aí suas tentativas pra gente dar uma olhada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Se coloco na linha `var retorno_bandeira = response.installments + "." + bandeira`, retorno de todos os dados vem `Undefined`, mas, se adiciono o nome da bandeira
>   diretamente na linha assim `response.installments.visa` vem tudo
>   normal, acredito que o problema esteja na forma de concatenar o nome
>   da bandeira ao retorno.

Uma outra forma de [acessar a propriedade do objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) é com a [notação de colchetes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
bandeira = $("#bandeira").val();
var retorno_bandeira = response.installments[bandeira];
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Você só precisa iterar sobre o array dentro de visa:

```js
var parcelas = getInstallments(),
    visa     = parcelas.installments.visa;

for( var i = 0; i < visa.length; i++ ) {
  var quantidade = visa[i].quantity,
      parcela    = visa[i].installmentAmount,
      valorTotal = visa[i].totalAmount;
  
      // aqui você usa os valores definidos pra montar o select
}
```

Comment: Amigão, sua solução funcionou. Editei o cordo adicionando o código usado, pois tenho mais uma dúvida relacionado ao javascript, pode me dá mais uma força!